# Basic Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, type-theory

I'm working through [Thompson's *Type Theory and Functional Programming*](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/). I've only read the first chapter and want to make sure I'm understanding the material.

The first problem asks to prove the transitivity of implication ($\Rightarrow$). In particular, if $((A\Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow C))$ then we can prove $A\Rightarrow C$.

My attempt:

$((A\Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow C)) \\
--------- \\
B \Rightarrow C \\
$

Discharging $B$ gives

$[B] \\
((A\Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow C)) \\
--------- \\
B \Rightarrow C \\
--------- \\
B\Rightarrow (B \Rightarrow C)
$

Discharging on $A$ gives the desired result. The technical point I want to check is whether I can simplify $B \Rightarrow (B \Rightarrow C)$ to $C$. I'm also a little bit uncertain about assuming $B$. It seems like this proof shouldn't need to do that.

I think I figured out my mistake. Is the derivation more like:

If we assume A then

$
A \qquad \quad (A\Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow C) \qquad \quad (A\Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow C) \\
- \qquad \quad -------- \qquad \quad --------- \\
A \qquad \quad A\Rightarrow B \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad B \Rightarrow C \\
------------------------ \\
B \qquad \quad B \Rightarrow C \\
------------------------ \\
C \\
$

And then we discharge on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful (it's in the Fitch style, but the difference is not essential):

[image]

Comment: I should have typed *just* a bit faster. It looks like you did exactly what I did in my added part, assuming the upside down triangle means that we assume $A$. For completeness, can you comment on my second approach?

Comment: @al92 Yes. The second looks good. It looks a bit strange stylistically, but it's correct.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was trying to follow the style in the book I linked.